# UIButton added programatically in UICollectionViewCell doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, uicollectionview

I am trying to add UIButton as a subview of another custom UIView inside of UICollectionViewCell 
However these two buttons which I am adding don't respond to touches and perform no actions.

Here I am initialising buttons:

```
let likeButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.anchor(width: 40, height: 40)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return button
}()

let commentButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 38.0/255.0, green: 37.0/255.0, blue: 37.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return button
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    likeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLike), for: .touchUpInside)
    commentButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleComment), for: .touchUpInside)
    setupViews()
}

func handleLike(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("like")
}

func handleComment(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("comment")
}
```

Adding as Subviews and setting Constraints:

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()
}

func setupViews() {

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [likesLabel, commentsLabel, viewsLabel])
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stackView.spacing = 4

    addSubview(newsImage)
    newsImage.addSubview(darkView)
    darkView.addSubview(newsTitleLabel)
    darkView.addSubview(stackView)
    darkView.addSubview(timeStampLabel)
    setButtonsStackView()

    addConstraintsWithFormaat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: newsImage)
    addConstraintsWithFormaat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: newsImage)
    newsImage.addConstraintsWithFormaat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: darkView)
    newsImage.addConstraintsWithFormaat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: darkView)

    stackView.anchor(top: nil, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 10, paddingBottom: -10, paddingRight: 0)
    newsTitleLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: leftAnchor, bottom: stackView.topAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 10, paddingBottom: -5, paddingRight: 0)
    timeStampLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: -10, paddingRight: 10)
}

func setButtonsStackView() {
    let buttonStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [likeButton, commentButton])
    buttonStackView.axis = .horizontal
    buttonStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
    buttonStackView.spacing = 10
    darkView.addSubview(buttonStackView)
    buttonStackView.anchor(top: darkView.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: darkView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 10)
}
```

As I am considering the problem might be with setting constraints and also as I've read from another post when you are adding a button as a subview of UIImageView the buttons never work.

Anyway I would be happy to get any suggestions!

PS:  I am using custom extensions for setting constraints. They work fine cuz I am using them in my projects pretty often.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that I have to set constraints of buttonStackView related to contentView of a cell.

```
    addSubview(buttonStackView)
    buttonStackView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil,
                           bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor,
                           paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10,
                           paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 10)
```

After that all buttons work fine and respond to touches.

Having buttons set as a subview of UIImageView was actually the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
 newsImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

> By default the `UserInteraction` property of `UIImageView` is set to
>   `false`. This the place where most of us makes mistake. So the main
>   thing to check in while adding any control to `UIImageView` is to set
>   its `isUserInteractionEnabled` property to `true`.